# phantom process died when I use node-horseman to open phantomjs with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, charles-proxy

When I used the 'node-horseman' to control phantomjs by Node.js, I have met a problem:

```
Unhandled rejection HeadlessError: Phantom Process died
at ClientRequest. (/Users/zhuyingda/nodejs/veneno/node_modules/node-phantom-simple/node-phantom-simple.js:655:12)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:288:9)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

I just run this code:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();
horseman
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.2 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0")
  .on('resourceRequested', function (requestData, networkRequest) {
    if(!/[png|jpg|js|css]$/.test(requestData.url)){
      console.log(requestData.url);
    }
  })
.open('http://www.zhuyingda.com')
.log() // prints out the number of results
.close();
```

I am sure that my network is fine and I can connect this website in my browser,and also I can curl this url and get response something.
If I open charles or other vpn program, the problem would be fixed. I wanna know why?

Comment: If it's a bug, try https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node , it works well.